# Picture of "scenery" appears on iPhone 6 lock screen

Tags: iphone, ios, malware, wallpaper

I just noticed that what I thought was "waveform bars" (for lack of a better description) on my iPhone 6 was actually a miniature landscape of houses and trees. What is it and where did it come from?

I upgraded from an iPhone 4S to iPhone 6S recently, so I'm not sure when I first noticed the issue, but I'm certain that it didn't exist on the iPhone 4. It's definitely not part of the original picture.

EDITED TO ADD: I was wrong. It was in fact part of the "original" picture (the one I uploaded to the phone), created by another program. I hadn't noticed it on the iPhone 4 because of the screen size/screen tilt. I'll leave the question in the slim chance someone else has encountered such a problem, but in any case it's been solved.

ORIGINAL QUESTION CONT.

It's barely noticeable (showing only the tops, which to me look like a waveform) until I tilt the phone, then it becomes apparent what it is.

Searching for quite some time on Google doesn't give me any answers. Anyone have any idea where this came from? I guess I could just change the image to see what happens, but in any case, it wouldn't explain where the image came from. My phone isn't jailbroken, so I'm doubtful it's some sort of malware that's gotten onto it (though not entirely impossible).

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: I'm confused. Is it only with this particular lock screen image, or do all of them have this issue?

Comment: @JMY1000 - only this one. I hadn’t verified it before, but now realize the image had some extra graphics on it from a collage maker app. (See my other comments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from the wallpaper you have set.

iOS hasn't added this — it's been added by wherever the photo came from. For example, a screenshot of a photo from Snapchat may have a filter on the bottom, then because you took a screenshot rather than using the original photo, something may be added to the bottom.

The scenery isn't moving independently; the whole image moves with perspective as you move the phone around. It's more noticeable on the edges as this is where the image moves the furthest, and you have a reference (the edge of the display) to compare as the picture moves.

Change your wallpaper to something else, perhaps to the original photo if the author can provide it to you without the edits.

Comment: My wife made the photo from a photo collage maker (can't remember which one at the moment), so it's the original picture. I'm not sure I understand what you mean. The scenery appears to move independently of the photo, so that's why I thought it was something added by iOS.

Comment: @Kevin The ‘original’ picture is the one which came from the camera before going through any app like a ‘collage maker’. The scenery doesn't move independently, the whole image moves with perspective as you move the phone around, but it's more noticeable on the edges as this is where the image moves the furthest and you have a point of reference (the edge of the display) to compare as the picture moves.

Comment: grgarside - thanks. Now that you’ve pointed me in the right direction, I’ve discovered it was in fact part of the picture. I never saw it before on my old phone because of the screen size and tilt perspective off. I just checked the top of the screen and noticed it too has scenery. It was most definitely something added by the collage maker, just hidden.